# How to modify a dataframe grouping columns values in a list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'comment':['any comment','any_comment','any comment','any comment','another comment','another comment'], 'key':[1,11,13,113,123,300]})
```

output:

```
comment                   key
any comment                1
any comment                11
any comment                13
any comment                113
any comment                12
another comment            123
another comment            300
```

And I want to modify the above dataframe to get this output:

```
comment                         key
any comment                [1,11,13,113,12]
another comment            [123,300]
```

The `key` columns now is a list.  Whatś the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
import pandas as pd

df.groupby('comment')['key'].apply(list)

comment
another comment          [123, 300]
any comment        [1, 11, 13, 113]
Name: key, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby('comment')['key'].agg(list)
```

```
comment
another comment          [123, 300]
any comment        [1, 11, 13, 113]
Name: key, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way - using comprehensions -

```py
print(*((k, list(v['key'])) for k, v in df.groupby(['comment'])))
```

**Output**

```
('another comment', [123, 300]) ('any comment', [1, 13, 113]) ('any_comment', [11])
```